# Start Android on external power

Tags: android

We're making a small app for Android. Thus it would be vital for us that the Android phone would start when it's attached on external power source. Is there any way to turn on your phone when the phone is getting more electricity, without any human actions?

Yours

-Heikki

Answer (score 2):

For my permanent mounted ZTE Blade the solution was to remove the battery. When USB power is connected, it will boot up. I don't know if that is an option for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

My guess that its up to hardware/firmware to start the device when power source is attached. Android has nothing to do with such low level events (as far as I know).

Comment: I thought that too. So propably I should flash the device with customized firmare? Any ideas of that?

Comment: I don't think its that easy. Normally firmware is highly customized for specific device, and even then you still need hardware support. But some devices are capable to show some progress when they are being charged after they were completely discharched. Overall, it takes great deal of time & expertize to reverse engineer firmware and modify it the way you want (legal issues aside).

Comment: Well.. I believe that the next best thing is the external battery pack. It ain't perfect solution, but will keep the phone on during the idle time.

Comment: You can provide external "power-source" with USB cable that can be connected to device. This is more cross-device compatible and can potentially keep more charge then any phone-battery. And by "power-source" I mean any good accumulator that is capable of producing enough current for long enough time. This is easier then hacking firmaware :)

Comment: Yep, and nice stand-by-times can be achieved by chaining the battery packs. Thanks mates:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED) intent

Comment: I think he means the case when device is already completely discharged and is off.

Comment: @Heikki Mustonen May be I don't understand you correctly. But phone is off e.g. power is off no applications is running so no intents.